# Display Custom Option Price In Order (E-mail, Backend & PDF)

Tags: custom-options

I was wondering if anyone knew how to display the Custom Option price on an order. I was able to have it show up in the cart and the review section of the checkout. Is there any possible way to have it show up in the email, admin backend & pdf printouts?

Thank You